# Vega-lite heatmap detect color

Tags: elasticsearch, colors, heatmap, vega, vega-lite

```
"data": {
"values": [
  {"x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0},
  {"x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 1},
  {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 5},
  {"x": 2, "y": 0, "z": 10},
  {"x": 4, "y": 0, "z": 16},
  {"x": 0, "y": 1, "z": 1},
  {"x": 1, "y": 1, "z": 2},
  {"x": 2, "y": 1, "z": 5},
  {"x": 3, "y": 1, "z": 10},
  {"x": 5, "y": 1, "z": 26}
]},
```

How do I set the color ?

> 0  < AVG(z) < 20  green
>
> 20 < AVG(z) < 25  yellow
>
> 25 < AVG(z) < 30  orange
>
> 30 < AVG(z) < 100  red

[Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-i1SxxcgSdTsV18-Z7dyWdpmjwAGVGOUvYEyj4jtJ-ru5QqlYW4o2oKfqYfm1bWh2zJTsY2bXtq2dWsbndT0yQAR1YJFzWic0qB0as0Qwf8oDoVxDDtFdyW4MtY0PRJkkDdhI3gVNN2yBiwE3aEgiAA)

Comment: Here we like to fix non working code. A lot of us would claim you try anything first. Please improve your question uising this guide [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bin transform along with a custom color scheme to map continuous values onto discrete colors. For example:

```
"color": {
  "field": "z",
  "scale": {"scheme": "redyellowgreen"},
  "type": "ordinal",
  "bin": {"step": 5}
}
```

The result with your chart looks something like this ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-DQgfTPmjYjLNj5yDldsrOY9+sN8ONfpH4XYSvskFgeGQpPeI8ljY38WqWOLkCTqdiuvH7OXuSztM0eAAyoxyl7AmVu31-nu5QqlYW4o2oGfqUf0GoAdaGXMl0CoRFqANbRq2dWsbndT0yQAR1YJFzWic0qB0as0Qwf8oDoVxDGHH99G4MtYyPRJkkDdhI3gVMt2yZiwC3aEgiAA)):

[image]

If you want very specific bins and colors, you can achieve this by adjusting the [Bin Parameters](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bin.html#bin-parameters) and using [Custom Color Schemes](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/).